# Cannot download sources from jar in intellij with maven

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I want to debug my maven project. I add a dependency Test that I have developped like this:

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

when I debug my program and I enter into Test dependent method I see /* compiled code */. If I click on attach source It does nothing and if I click on download source, I get a pop up message saying:
Cannot download sources, 
Sources not found for:
com.mycompany.group:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

I also tried to execute :

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

But when I try to enter my dependent method I just see /* compiled code */
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not uncommon for sources to be unavailable for custom jars, since developers would have to explicitly create a source jar using the [Maven Source 
Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html) and install this jar in a remote repository. There's a [Maven cookbook page](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html) for this as well.

If you have no way of adding sources for your dependencies, then I think your best bet would be to [use a decompiler](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7100-java-decompiler-intellij-plugin).

Comment: hi the jar Test is a jar that I developped myself so is there a way to attach sources?

Comment: Yes - look at the two links I provided about the Maven Source plugin